When is the product of two orthogonal projectors an orthogonal projector?
Let $V$ and $W$ be two vector subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$, let $p_V$ be the orthogonal projector onto $V$, and let $p_W$ be the orthogonal projector onto $W$. When is it the case that $p_Vp_W$ is the orthogonal projector onto $V\cap W$?
I know that this is equivalent to requiring that $p_V$ and $p_W$ commute, but is there a corresponding geometric condition for $V$ and $W$? For example, if $V=W$ or if $V\perp W$ it is certainly true that $p_Vp_W$ is the orthogonal projector onto $V\cap W$, but the condition is not necessary.

I don't know if this is geometric enough for you, but this is equivalent to there existing an ONB for $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that some subset is a basis for $V$ and some other subset is a basis for $W$.

Let $Z=V\cap W$, and write orthogonal direct sums $V=Z\oplus V'$ and $W=Z\oplus W'$. Then you want to require that $V'$ and $W'$ are orthogonal subspaces.
You can easily check that $P_WP_V(v') = P_W(v')\in W'$ and $P_VP_W(w')\in V'$ for any $v'\in V'$ and $w'\in W'$, so $P_VP_W=P_{V\cap W}$ if and only if $P_W(v')=0$ and $P_V(w')=0$, which yields that condition.
